# how to extract the specific words from a string in R?

Tags: r, string, extract, cpu-word

how can I extract "7-9", "2-5" and "2-8", then paste to new column as event_time?
event_details
2.9(S) 7-9 street【Train】#2097
2.1(S) 2-5 street【Train】#2012
2.2(S) 2-8A TBC【Train】#202

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really shared the logic to extract the numbers but based on limited data that you have shared we can do :

```
df$new_col <- sub('.*(\\d+-\\d+).*', '\\1', df$event_details)

df
#               event_details new_col
#1 2.9(S) 7-9 street【Train】     7-9
#2 2.1(S) 2-5 street【Train】     2-5
#3   2.2(S) 2-8A TBC【Train】     2-8
```

Or same using `str_extract`

```
df$new_col <- stringr::str_extract(df$event_details, "\\d+-\\d+")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(event_details = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("2.1(S) 2-5 street【Train】", 
"2.2(S) 2-8A TBC【Train】", "2.9(S) 7-9 street【Train】"), class = 
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```